# how to replace "?" and "=" sign with "/" in URL - PHP htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

i am working on project, which is running XAMPP localhost and PHP MYSQLI,
my question : how i replace "?","=" signs with "/" slash. ?
like, my url is "archive?date=2017-06-02&p=4"
and i want to force it "archive/2017-08-02/4"

i found many codes on stackoverflow and some other sites, but that are not working for me.
if codes are working then, CSS files and GET method doesn't work on my project.

complete code of .htaccess is given below.

```
        Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^([^=]*)=([^=]*)=(.*) /$1/$2/$3 [N]
    RewriteRule ^([^=]*)=([^=]*)$ $1/$2 [L]


    RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^archive archive.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^about about.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^article article.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^news news.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^video videos.php [NC,L]




    RewriteRule ^video?vid=([0-9]+) videos.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^article?num=([0-9]+) article.php?num=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^editorial?num=([0-9]+) editorial.php?num=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^news?news=([0-9]+) news.php?news=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It's usually a simple rewrite rule (if not a file, redirect to index) and a routing system

Comment: it would be like this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^date=([\d-]+)&p=(\d+)$"` ↲ `RewriteRule "^archive$" "/archive/%1/%2" [R,L]`

Comment: not working yet :(

Comment: its not loading CSS and JavaScripts and not working GET method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check against the query string in a rewrite rule. You need rewrite conditions for that:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=([^&]+)&p=(.+)
RewriteRule ^archive/? /archive/%1/%2?
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=81e85c09-d505-5206-ab14-6c5059107808

If you want to actually redirect just add `[R=301,L]` to the end of the `RewriteRule`.

However, looking at the above I suspect you have your script sitting listening at `/archive/index.php?data=foo&p=bar` but want URLs to be like `/archive/date/p`, ie pretty.

This is actually a very common misconception about how htaccess URL rewrites work when you first get into them.

RewriteRules will mask or redirect URLs for you but they cannot change the underlying location a script is located at and thus the address used to pass it information.

In other words - you can mask `/archive/index.php?data=foo&p=bar` as `/archive/date/p` so that requests made to `/archive/date/p` resolve to `/archive/index.php?data=foo&p=bar`, but you cannot make it so that if you enter `/archive/index.php?data=foo&p=bar` as URL you have the URL change to `/archive/date/p` while still serving content from `/archive/date/p`. It has to be either or.

If this all sounds about right my advice would be as follows:

First, put your code into a different file, say `/archive/script.php`.

Next add the following to your htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=([^&]+)&p=(.+)
RewriteRule ^archive/? /archive/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /archive/script.php?date=$1&p=$2
```

Note that the first two lines are the same as before, but now there is a new line that looks for the masked URL format of `/archive/date/p` and sends it off to the actual script, which is handled by the new RewriteRule.

The behaviour of the new rule is demoed here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=06751667-f16f-5c13-91eb-dd5cffdc6db3

Hope this makes sense / helps.